# How do I make authenticated requests to Microsoft Graph from a Subscription webhook endpoint for other users when a change notification comes in?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Azure AD authentication, via an Azure AD Application (setup for both organization/school and personal accounts) and users authorize via a standard OpenConnect scenario from a website.

I also have an Azure Web Service that listens for change notifications for various things (using this same Client/Secret/Tenant=common), such as Contacts and Events. This all works well, however, when (for example) a new Contact is created or updated, I need to use the Graph SDK to grab the actual Contact and update a secondary data store.

Right now I use the typical `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` however there always seems to be an issue accessing other user's Contacts, as I typically get something like "The token contains no permissions or permissions cannot be understood."

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    var accessToken = GetAccessToken().Result;

    requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}));

return graphClient;
```

It seems like this delegate access token that gets created should be able to grab an actual Contact since its setup in Scopes and the user has accepted.

Any ideas on what I need to do differently to access other users Contacts directly from the service?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to obtain Application access to the tenant or request the Delegated `offline_access` scope.

If you use `offline_access` you will receive an additional token called `refresh_token`. You will need to store this for each user and use it to obtain a new `access_token` when you receive a notification and need to make calls into Graph. See [Use the refresh token to get a new access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token) in the documentation for detailed instructions.

Comment: This would be true with legacy scenarios, however we are using the latest Microsoft.Identity.Web with ITokenAcquisition. In the service (when Subscription notifications come in) we really don't have any concept of a User Context or original token/code, and so I was hoping, since these are all delegated Admin Consent, there would just be a way to create a token to pass to the Graph SDK that would be "valid" for any user that has authenticated. Thoughts?

Comment: This isn't legacy, it is simply how OData works (Access vs Refresh tokens). If you don't request `offline_access` and store the refresh token (either directly or the token cache from MSAL itself), there is no way to rehydrate a token to call the Graph on behalf of the user. Your only other option would be to use Application scopes but I assumed you've already decided against using this model.

Comment: To clarify, offline_access is already part of this scenario, however since we are suing the latest version, the ITokenAcquisition and entire process obscures the concept of grabbing refresh tokens. It has been determined there is actually an issue in the process and can be reproduced when attempting to use the following sample service: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample. Folks involved in the repo are investigating a fix.